# Query with alias in joomla 1.5 doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I m trying to output introtext of article selected by their alias

```
<?php 
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content  WHERE alias=branchfr";
$db->setQuery($query);
$text= $db->loadResult(); 
?>
```

Is it normal?
Does it change in joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement is missing quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content  WHERE alias = 'branchfr'";
```

Comment: You are fantastic it is working!!! Thank you so much ! But one more question I would like to search in 2 table does it work that one: `$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content, jmo_xxx  WHERE alias='branchen'";'

Comment: Thank you very much ! It is not working but my query is somewhere wrong. Have beautiful day! Thanks a lot!